# Why are text files created on ubuntu not recognised as windows notepad files?

Tags: file-format

Whenever I want to access a text file created on ubuntu using Windows, it looks as if the file extension is not recognised. I always have to choose open with and then select notepad.

Is there any way to create text files on ubuntu that are identical to windows text files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to save it with an extension of ".txt" and select encoding (it appears when you save) as compatible with windows.

Answer (score 2):

Txt files in ubuntu are made without an extension. thus every txt files in ubuntu 
is `ubuntu` instead of `ubuntu.txt` you have to manually save it as .txt. or rename
the `ubuntu` to `ubuntu.txt`

Comment: even you have to change the encoding .....

Answer (score 0):

Remember that you must choose the correct line ending when you save the file. In 'Save As' dialog, select 'Windows' as line ending option.  Otherwise, 'newline' character will not be recognized. If you are using Windows, you can open the file with Wordpad and save the file.